# Android studio: How to source android jar in a module

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just switched to android studio from eclipse (because of FB SDK), so this might be a stupid question. In my android project, I created a module (Java Library) which I call dbUtils, where I am using greenDAO to save data in SQLite. It requires an import

```
import android.content.Context;
```

It cannot find this class. I can't figure out what dependency I need to add. Under the :app module, this is recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **android-library** plugin in your *build.gradle* file. Take look [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-Library-Project). This way the Android Studio will know that this project is an android library (not just a java one) and import the needed classes. I have used it and it works. Here is my *build.gradle* file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile project(':validationutils')
}
```